# Append a new line character at every record passing through CamelKafkaAzureBlobSink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, azure-blob-storage, apache-kafka-connect

We are currently working on a data pipeline stack where we have used CamelAzurestorageblobSinkConnector(0.9.x) which is basically reading a specific topic from Kafka(cp-kafka-5.0.0) and appending each record to a specific Azure AppendBlob.

Syncing work is happening perfectly but *one glitch we have found in the stack*.

> *The JSON records have been appended to the blob file without any line break* like below -

> {"uuid":"6e7190e2-987d-44f5-9b20-ba854d8d4274","foo":"bar"}{"uuid":"6f0d3912-b7c1-4cc4-a41b-0d54cd623373","foo":"bar"}{"foo":"bar"}

And this affects the further processing of the blob file.

Our *CamelAzurestorageblobSinkConnector.properties* looks like below -

```
name=CamelAzure-storage-blobSinkConnector
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.azurestorageblob.CamelAzurestorageblobSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
camel.sink.marshal=json-jackson
# comma separated topics to get messages from
topics=test-topic

camel.sink.path.accountName=<storage-account>
camel.sink.path.containerName=<blob-container>
camel.sink.endpoint.blobName=data/test-topic/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${date:now:HH}-id.json
camel.sink.endpoint.accessKey=<account-key>
camel.sink.endpoint.operation=commitAppendBlob
camel.sink.endpoint.createAppendBlob=true
camel.sink.endpoint.blobType=appendblob
```

Any help here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You could try adding a transforms property, but I don't think there any built in ones to do this, so you may need to write your own

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your response. Actually, I have successfully added an extra field to every JSON record that are passing through the SInk connector but struggling to add new line char at the end of every record. Here, I am a bit confused on the strategy to implement the same. I have tried with serialize the JSON record into string, then adding a new line char and then deserialize technique over the updated record string. But no luck still! Could you please help here?

Comment: Adding a field is different because it actually parses the event and rebuilds an internal Struct object. Like I said, writing a custom transform is the only thing that would work here, and yes, you'd have to use StringConverter rather than JSON

Comment: Or maybe look at the source code and see what can be done to add line breaks between events https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector/tree/main/connectors/camel-azure-storage-blob-kafka-connector/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/kafkaconnector/azurestorageblob Otherwise, open a Github issue to have the devs recommend a workaround

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your valuable feedback. As you said, I would like to try it out using StringConverter instead of JsonConverter. And keep you updated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for the suggestion @OneCricketeer.

I am successfully able to append line separator at each event/record passing through the sink connector.

*Have done the below configuration at the camel component level :*

> 1. Modify the key and value converter from JSONConverter to StringConverter. Here is the modified CamelAzurestorageblobSinkConnector.properties

```
name=CamelAzure-storage-blobSinkConnector 
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.azurestorageblob.CamelAzurestorageblobSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
topics=test-topic
camel.sink.path.accountName=<storage-account>
camel.sink.path.containerName=<blob-container>
camel.sink.endpoint.blobName=data/test-topic/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${date:now:HH}-id.json
camel.sink.endpoint.accessKey=<account-key>
camel.sink.endpoint.operation=commitAppendBlob
camel.sink.endpoint.createAppendBlob=true
camel.sink.endpoint.blobType=appendblob
```

> 2. Override the apply() method like this -

```
 @Override
 private R apply (R record) {
    
    String value = (String) operatingValue(record);
    
    String updated_value = value+System.lineSeparator();
    System.out.println("UPDATED SMT RECORD: "+updated_value);

    return newRecord(record, null, updated_value);
  }
```

> Now we have the records inside the blob like below -

```
{"uuid":"6e7190e2-987d-44f5-9b20-ba854d8d4274","foo":"bar"} 
{"uuid":"6f0d3912-b7c1-4cc4-a41b-0d54cd623373","foo":"bar"}
```